# ListActivity во вкладке TabActivity

Tags: android, java

Возможно вопрос банален. У меня есть приложение в корне лежит TabHost. Мне нужно добиться отображения ArrayList на одной из вкладок. Есть примеры где реализовано отображение ArrayList, но там при этом используется ListActivity. Так же можно вынести все это в отдельный класс и создать intent, но при этом мой лист с данными отображается как новая вкладка. Вообщем вопрос ставлю так, как создать ArrayList, заполнить его данными и вернуть как View, что бы можно было сделать Layout.addView() на мою страницу?

Comment: А обычный ListView вам не подойдет? В качестве параметров он принимает, например, `ArrayAdapter<String>`.

Comment: Да, спасибо вполне подошло.

Answer (score 1):

Вы немного припозднились с TabActivity. Советую [почитать](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TabActivity.html) внимательно. По поводу оформления списка советую почитать [это](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html).

Comment: спасибо за ссылки. К сожалению Fragment начинает работать с API11 Android introduced fragments in Android 3.0 (API level 11).
И все таки что делать в моем случае, как вернуть ArrayList как view обычный, это же обычная задача должна быть?

Comment: Есть [пакет поддержки][1] для ранних версий. По-моему на странице про TabActivity об этом есть упоминание.

[1]: http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html

Comment: [Вот][1] еще пошаговое how to

[1]: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-compatibility-working-with-fragments/